# LIKE operator as a replacement for RegEx

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My task is to select entries for the following mask - SNNN000
Where:

- "N" – any numerical symbol;
- "S" – any numerical or alphabetic symbol(Latin);
- "0" - any numerical or alphabetic symbol (Latin), can be
  missed;

Here's what I got - "[0-9A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]".
There was a problem with "0", how can I make it so that the mask can ignore the conditions for this symbol? All entries except the 5th(Id) from the @table table should be displayed.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
    id      INT
    ,Txt    NVARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT  INTO @table (id, Txt)
VALUES (1, N'S123AB1')
,(2, N'S123')
,(3, N'S123A')
,(4, N'S123AB')
,(5, N'S123.@!');

SELECT * 
FROM @table AS t
WHERE t.Txt LIKE N'[0-9A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]'
```

I understand that I could add conditions via the OR operator. But I would like to do it in a single expression and I could do it in regular expressions "[0-9A-Za-z]\d{3}[0-9A-Za-z]?[0-9A-Za-z]?[0-9A-Za-z]?". As I understand it, there are no full regular expressions in SQL, if I am wrong, then I would appreciate an explanation.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    @table AS t
WHERE   t.Txt LIKE N'[0-9A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]'
        OR  t.Txt LIKE N'[0-9A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]';
```

Comment: The standard `LIKE` operator doesn't recognize character classes.  You're using an extension if that works at all.  You'll need 4 related `LIKE` terms — with 0, 1, 2 and 3 of the 'optional' terms.  You're better off using a regex unless there are compelling reasons to use `LIKE` instead (because the OR'd term is a performance inhibitor, and clumsy as anything).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You have roughly twice as many points as I do.  I feel undervalued.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen — when you've done another 4 years slave labour at the SO Q&A system, you may be able to catch up (to where I am now).  You got a late start; that makes it harder.  

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for your reply. But I understand there are no regular expressions in MS SQL? If I am wrong, I would appreciate an example.

Comment: @Tibomso There are probably external packages/UDFs etc. which you can import into SQL Server.  Jonathan: Yeah, I started late, and then low-lying fruit was almost all plucked already.

Comment: I am no SQL Server expert — ask Tim instead.  I know some bits and pieces because of commonality with other DBMS, but otherwise, I have to manual bash like you do.  But I'll admit — if SQL Server doesn't support regular expressions, that's a _very_ compelling reason to use `LIKE` instead.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler As of now, SQL Server is basically the only major enterprise database with no built in regex support.  There are UDFs available though.  So using enhanced `LIKE` here is a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, using `OR` is probably the best you can do using SQL Server's enhanced `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @table AS t
WHERE
    t.Txt LIKE N'[0-9A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]' OR
    t.Txt LIKE N'[0-9A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9A-Za-z]' OR
    t.Txt LIKE N'[0-9A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]' OR
    t.Txt LIKE N'[0-9A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]';
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method I can think of is:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM @table AS t
WHERE (t.Txt + 'AAA') LIKE '[0-9A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]%' AND
      LEN(t.Txt) BETWEEN 4 AND 7;
```

This adds three extra characters and checks that the first 7 characters match.  It then validates the length of the column.